# Variable accessed for Read point on same line , will OS read the memory twice?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, operating-system

Please help me understand how compiler/OS responds to the following program line in C,

```
int c;

void task1()
{
c+=c;  // This line is actually c=c+c; 2 read point 1 write
}
```

Will the memory be read twice or only single time ?

Comment: It depends on what code the compiler generates and on the CPU. The compiler might as well optimize it as `c *= 2` or even `c <<= 1` or something completely different. You have to create (an optimized release) executable and look at the generated code.

Comment: There is no guarantee about the number of accesses to the variable. Nor that it will be - or will not be - stored in memory or a register or on the moon. As given the compiler also could generate no code at all.

Comment: For me read 1 time to a cpu register, sum itself, write 1 time. But for to be sure you have to find the argument pass to the compiler for see assembly translation for that code

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the processor, the compiler, and the compiler options. On a processor that that has a multiply to memory instruction and with an compiler that is not in debug mode you might get code generated something like

```
MULL2 #2, C
```

The memory will be read once and written once. On a processor that does all operations in registers, you might get something like:

```
MOVL C, R3
MULL #2, R3
MOVL R3, C
```

Comment: The code in the question is `c += c`, not `c += 1`.

Comment: Let me adjust then.